# Lektor OS X desktop app install shell command fails when Anaconda is installed

Tags: lektor

Downloading, installing and running the desktop app works as expected. When I go to the Lektor menu and select "Install Shell Command" there is a popup notifying me that installing the shell command requires admin rights. No matter if I click no or yes, nothing happens, no password request, nothing.

In the terminal, when I type

```
lektor quickstart
```

I get

```
-bash: lektor: command not found
```

macOS 10.12.5, Python 2.7 and 3.4 (Anaconda)

Comment: Are you using the correct packages for Anaconda?

Comment: Nikl, I simply didn't manage to find out that Lektor can be installed using Anaconda. See my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (by Gonzalo Peña-Castellanos, thanks!):

```
$ conda install lektor -c conda-forge
```